# Accessing a tabBarController from a class that didn't create it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I'm developing an iPhone app, in which the first thing the end user sees is a "home" screen with five UIButtons.  Upon tapping any one of those buttons, They're taken to a tab bar controller view with five tabs on the bottom, corresponding to the each of the UIButtons on the (now) previous home screen.

I'm currently creating my tab bar controller in my App Delegate, and loading the home view controller in the same place.

But I can't get the UIButtons in the Home View Controller to work.  I call the different tabs like such:

```
- (void) homeBtnSelect:(UIButton *)button {
    if (button == button1) {
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
    }
    if (button == button2) {
        self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
    }
    //etc etc...
}
```

I'm assuming I'll need to load the tabBarController into the home view controller.  But I don't know how to do that. Can anyone help?

I can provide more code if needed.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does you `homeBtnSelect:` is being called?

Comment: have you implemented the delegate for tabBarController.... as you are changing tabBarController.selectedIndex you will need to handle delegate by youself....... any other thing you are doing to change the tab?

Comment: No. What do you mean by "handle the delegate" though?

Comment: homeBtnSelect is indeed being called. I've tested with an NSLog. :)

Comment: @property(nonatomic, assign) UIViewController *selectedViewController..... set this viewController..... rather than setting selectedIndex.....

Answer (score 0):

In order to select particular `viewController` you have to set `selectedViewController` property..... you can do this by getting viewcontroller from `tabBarController.viewControllers` array..... and then setting `selectedViewController` property.......